# My PK will not be incremented/generated, Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, mariadb

When I want to add this NotebookModel to my DB, it doesn't get an ID (it remains with the default value of an INT32).

Normally after `SaveChangesAsync()` the object is automatically assigned an ID, this also works for other models. But not with these, although they are built the same way.

**so that a few questions are answered:**
*-Yes, the database is created

-Yes, the model is in the DbSet

-Yes, I have already rebuilt the API*

Am I overlooking something?

**C# Code:**

```
NotebookModel newNotebook = new NotebookModel();

_db.Notebook.Add(newNotebook);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**NoteBook-Model:**

```
public class NotebookModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<NoteModel> Notebook { get; set; } = new List<NoteModel>();
}
```

**Note-Model:**

```
public class NoteModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is missing!")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? Value { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CreationDate is missing!")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = default!;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastEditDate is missing!")]
    public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

**DB-Context:**

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

    public DbSet<NotebookModel> Notebook { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NoteModel> Note { get; set; } 
}
```

**The error response:**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Could not save changes. Please configure your entity type accordingly.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT VALUES();
SELECT `Id`
FROM `Notebook`
WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `I...' at line 2
```

**My Csproj-file:**

```
<ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.4" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.4">
     <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
     <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
     </PackageReference>
          <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.4" />
          <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.4">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
     </PackageReference> 
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: What's the *exact* error? Have you tried running that SQL query directly? What error do you get in this case? Does the table match the class? Your code shows a `NotebookModel` but the query uses `Notebook`. How was that entity configured?

Comment: "... running that SQL query directly?" - No, I just created the database with "Add-Migration" & tried to add an empty notebook via C#. Actually there should be no error regarding "NoteModel" because the list is empty.

Comment: To your question, yes the tables exist.

Comment: Which EF or EF Core, and which provider are you using? Post the actual package and versions. The error complains about `'DEFAULT VALUES();`. MariaDB does have differences from MySQL. Oracle's ADO.NET and EF Core providers aren't well maintained. The truly open source `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` package fixes a lot of the problems of the Oracle provider

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i add the csproj-file to the question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But the fact that confuses me is that my UserModel (which you don't see here) is built the same way but gets assigned an ID. I have been using this package/packages for ages.

Comment: Since you use EF Core, abandon the buggy Oracle provider and use the far more popular, stable and truly open source[Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) package. That, and the MySqlConnector ADO.NET driver fix a lot of the bugs in Oracle's drivers *and* support MariaDB syntax. For example, MariaDB doesn't need the extra `SELECT` to  retrieve the newly created IDs (plural). The INSERT command has a `RETURNING` clause that can return the new ID directly. So du PostgreSQL and SQL Server (OUTPUT) but not MySQL

Comment: The Pomelo driver has 37M downloads. The Oracle driver has 2M downloads

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh well, I always took this NuGet/Driver because I thought it was good and it is an official source. And I always thought yours was a "noname" nuget with Security bugs. 
But now for me, does the syntax stay the same, or what effectively changes for me?

Comment: Oracle's driver didn't release any versions for months or years at one point. It didn't even have real async operations.  Eventually they had to abandon their driver and start from scratch. Oracle has absolutely no reason to support a competing database like MariaDB, kill its cash-cow database (Oracle Database) or help competing environments (.NET).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much, it's almost embarrassing.
But with my other models it worked, and it has always worked. 
Anyway, I installed it, I had to change my service minimally but then it worked right away. 
I don't notice any difference, except that it works.
If you like, you can write a answer with this information and I will rate it as helpful. I can not mark your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I or rather PanagiotisKanavos found the solution.

I have always used `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore`, I never had problems with it until now.
This is a driver from `Oracle` that has never been maintained that much. It also has only *2 million downloads*.
After that PanagiotisKanavos recommended me `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`. It is better known, more stable and not so vulnerable. It also has *37 million downloads*.

I installed this Nuget, and had to change **only 1 thing** in my `Program.cs`, it was no longer called

```
.UseMySQL(connectionString)
```

but

```
.UseMySql(connectionString, mySqlDbVersion)
```

For this there was also the perfect build in solution, and it look like this

```
.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString))
```

But to sum up, the **syntax is the same**, all commands **work as usual** and my strange **error was fixed**!